# How to set values in Makefile.poisx

Tags: linux, ubuntu, arm, nrf52, nrf51

I am trying to build nrfsdk for the nrf52840 armgcc, running make gives following error.

```
su@su-desktop:~/nRF/nRF5_SDK_17.1.0_ddde560/examples/peripheral/template_project/pca10056/blank/armgcc$ make
/home/su/gcc-arm-none-eabi/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc: 1: cannot open @@P�@8: No such file
/home/su/gcc-arm-none-eabi/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
Cannot find: '/home/su/gcc-arm-none-eabi/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc'.
Please set values in: "/home/su/nRF/nRF5_SDK_17.1.0_ddde560/components/toolchain/gcc/Makefile.posix"
according to the actual configuration of your system.
../../../../../../components/toolchain/gcc/Makefile.common:129: *** Cannot continue.  Stop.
su@su-desktop:~/nRF/nRF5_SDK_17.1.0_ddde560/examples/peripheral/template_project/pca10056/blank/armgcc$
```

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure you actually have the `arm-none-eabi-gcc` toolchain installed.

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc --version
```

if you don't have it, you can find it here: https://developer.arm.com/downloads/-/gnu-rm

2. if you do have it installed but are not sure of where to find it, run this

```
$ whereis arm-none-eabi-gcc
arm-none-eabi-gcc /opt/arm-none-eabi-gcc/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc <-- this line can be different for you
```

3. then you can edit the Makefile.posix file (ex by opening it in a text editor)

go to the directory of your nrfSDK install, then `components>toolchain>gcc>Makefile.posix`
and edit the `GNU_INSTALL_ROOT` field (for me that was /opt/arm-none-eabi-gcc/bin) and `GNU_VERSION` field to whatever toolchain version you installed (9.3.1 in my case)

Hope it helps :)￼